# Mac terminal keeps using SSH key with same fingerprint when running git clone

Tags: ssh, git, rsa

It doesn't matter what I do, create new SSH keys, add them manually to Heroku, delete all keys from Heroku and add a new one, force delete the entire ~/.ssh folder, overwrite id_rsa keys, create ~/.ssh/config file, create a keygen with -C flag, create a dsa key pair instead of rsa, deleting the keychains from the Keychain Access utility in Mac OS X, and I've just about every SU question on this.

But I keep always getting the same error message, with the same fingerprint when I run

`$ git clone git@heroku.com:app-name-0000.git -o heroku`

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'x.x.x.x' to the list of known hosts.


 !  Your key with fingerprint 48:dd:XX...XX is not authorized to access app-name-0000.

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I remember having this problem some time ago with Github and gave up.
I really stumped as to what to do. (Reinstall Mac OS X?)

Comment: `ssh-agent -D` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X has an SSH agent running in user sessions; use [`ssh-add`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-add) to manage keys.

(I hope you are not serious about removing keychains in `Keychain Access`; removing the wrong one will lock you out of your account, and you may not be able to recover easily.)

Comment: It works :) Cannot believe how ridiculously simple that solution was. I can now clone and push to origin master with git. And don't worry, I deleted only what one user instructed, I didn't touch anything else. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [heroku help file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-repository-ssh-fingerprints).  You have to manually match the provided SSH key to this fingerprint: `8b:48:5e:67:0e:c9:16:47:32:f2:87:0c:1f:c8:60:ad`

Try removing the entry from ~/.ssh/known_hosts then adding this to ~/.ssh/config:

Host heroku.com
 VerifyHostKeyDNS yes

Then accept the warning when you try cloning again.